# unable to call searchbox phtml on static block in magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2

I want to add searchbox in main content on homepage, i created a static block and tried to call form.mini but it throws a error.
code in static block:-

```
{{ block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search.custom" as="topSearchcustom" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml"  }}
```

The error I am facing is:-

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

try this code in static block

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml"}}
```

hope it helps you